# How do you output a resources file from C# application?

Tags: c#, file, resources

I am using Visual C# 2010 Express. I would like to put .dotx or Word Template files into the Resources folder of my application and when it is installed, output the files to a different directory preferably C://Myfolder/. I couldn't find anything about it here. Are there any ways to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on Resources (in "Properties"), and then on the arrow next to "strings" and choose "files".

Then drag the file in and name it. then use:

```
Properties.Resources.fileName;
```

which will be a `byte[]`, and save it using:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile) + @"\filename", Properties.Resources.fileName);
```

Answer (score 3):

Why would you want this as a resource? Why not bundle it as part of the installer package which can work out where to put the file when your application is installed?

Comment: How do you do that? Do you have any links from where I can refer from?

Comment: Depends entirely on what install engine you're using I'm afraid, personally I use Inno Setup from http://www.jrsoftware.org/